# Comparison of two Character Arrays in C++ using Comparison Operator

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, comparison, implicit-conversion

How does the comparison operator work when doing a comparison between two character arrays?

Consider the following program,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char arr1[5] = { 'T','e','s','t' };
    char arr2[10] = { 't','e' };
    if (arr1 < arr2)
        cout << "Yes";
    else if (arr1 > arr2)
        cout << "No";
    else
        cout << "0";
}
```

The way I know is it should print `Yes` because the first character of `arr1` has an ASCII value of `84` while the ASCII value of first character of `arr2` is `116`so technically it should print Yes.

However, this program gives the output of `No` when run on Visual Studio.

I thought that it might be comparing the **addresses of character arrays**. To test this, I swapped the variable names and ran this program,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char arr2[5] = { 'T','e','s','t' };
    char arr1[10] = { 't','e' };
    if (arr1 < arr2)
        cout << "Yes";
    else if (arr1 > arr2)
        cout << "No";
    else
        cout << "0";
}
```

But this again gave `Yes` as output, meaning the addresses of character arrays did not matter in the comparison.

Can anyone tell how is this comparison being done?

Comment: It compares their addresses, which is almost never what you want. There is no requirement that changing the order of their definitions will change their relative addresses.

Comment: Given that the arrays' contents are never used and never change, the compiler is free  to eliminate them entirely.

Comment: When you do `arr1 < arr2` it's equivalent to `&arr1[0] < &arr2[0]`. That is, you compare two completely unrelated pointers. If you want to compare the *content* of the arrays either use loops (but remember the size difference!), or use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) which have overloaded comparison operators that does the proper things.

Comment: Or, since you have two C-style null-terminated strings, you can use [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp). But I really recommend you switch to proper C++ containers.

Comment: The behaviour of the `operator <` is dependent on the compiler you are using. But my gut feelings are saying that the compiler puts a comparison between the number of characters you have put in the initializer.

Comment: @akmcoder no behavior of `operator <` is undefined here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the condition of the if statement

```
if (arr1 < arr2)
```

the both arrays are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements and these addresses are compared that results in undefined behavior for the `operator <`.

Pay attention to if you will compare string literals like

```
if ( "Hello" == "Hello" )
//...
```

then the value of the expression can be either true or false dependent on compiler options: whether identical string literals are stored as one string literal or as separate string literals.

As for the comparison of character arrays that do not contain strings then you can use the standard algorithm `std::lexicographical_compare`.

Otherwise if character arrays contain strings as in your example then you can use the standard C string function `strcmp`.

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char arr1[5] = { 'T','e','s','t' };
    char arr2[10] = { 't','e' };

    if (std::lexicographical_compare( arr1, arr1 + 4, arr2, arr2 + 2 ))
    {
        std::cout << "The array arr1 is less than the array arr2\n";
    }

    if ( std::strcmp( arr1, arr2 ) < 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "The array arr1 is less than the array arr2\n";
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
The array arr1 is less than the array arr2
The array arr1 is less than the array arr2
```

Answer (score 0):

It definitely compares addresses and not values of array items. You should not rely on address allocations in this manner.

Anyways, you can check:

- string.h for strcmp() // need to terminate your char arrays with '\0'
- string::compare()
- std::lexicographical_compare()

Answer (score 0):

Consider using string_view, it has hardly any overhead. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view

note : this example compares the strings at compile time for easy testing, but it works at runtime too (without the constexpr)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string_view>

int main()
{
    constexpr std::string_view cvw1{ "test" };
    constexpr std::string_view cvw2{ "te" };
    static_assert(cvw1 > cvw2);

    return 0;
}
```